# ANSI Escape Sequences converted to strings won't work on visual studios

Tags: c++

I've been trying to change the color of selected text using ANSI escape sequences turned into strings. It works on online compilers but not visual studios which just spits out the actual escape sequence and not its effect.

```
  string normal="\u001b[0m";
  string bold="\u001b[1m";
  string italic="\u001b[3m";
  string blink="\u001b[5m";
  string black="\u001b[30m";
  string red="\u001b[31m";
  string green="\u001b[32m";
  string yellow="\u001b[33m";
  string blue="\u001b[34m";
  string magenta="\u001b[35m";
  string cyan="\u001b[36m";
```

This is what I have.
This is how it is formatted.

cout<<"Whatever" << bold <<"Special stuff";

Comment: IIRC the MS-Windows console does not support ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: @RichardCritten it at works for at least come version. The bolding works for me in both CMD and PowerShell on W7 Enterprise.

Comment: See [Microsoft's virtual terminal support documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). It has sample code to enable escape sequence processing.

Comment: @ThomasJager Was trying to remember etc, found a likely dupe.